# Passing function to .on() in plain object

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I want to call a custom function on mouse enter.

My current code looks like this:

```
var myFunction = function(element)
{
   //do something with element
}

$( selector ).on({
    mouseenter: myFunction($(this)),
    mouseleave: myFunction($(this))
}, ' selector ');
```

My problem is that it seems like `myFunction()` isn't even called. Does this even work or did I mess up something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how functions work in javascript. Here's a simple way to make mouseenter call a function.

```
$(selector).on({
    mouseenter: function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
});
```

This makes sense. When the mouseenter event gets called, the function executes. Great.

Your problem is that this code:

```
var functionToCall = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}

$(selector).on({
    mouseenter: functionToCall(event);
});
```

does not actually do the same thing as the previous example.

When you put brackets after a function name, you are **calling** the function. What `mouseenter` wants is a function reference - javascript will call the function reference you give it for you every time the event occurs.

What we assigned `mouseenter` to in the first example was an anonymous function reference - we didn't actually call the function we created. Javascript was doing that for us. In the second example, we called the function, so `mouseenter` was actually set to the return value of the function, not to the function itself.

To fix this, you just need to pass a function reference to the event instead of calling the function. Note, you can't directly pass parameters this way (it's not impossible, but you shouldn't need to), but $(this) will still be the same.

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var element = $(this);
    // code...
}

$(selector).on({
    mouseenter: myFunction,
    mouseleave: myFunction
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation, helped a lot! Now everything works like a charm and I learned something about JS functions! :)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't passing a function. You are calling the function **immediately** and passing its return value.

Since you want to call the function, with an argument, and the value of that argument isn't determined until the event fires, you need to create a new function.

```
function use_myFunction_as_event_handler(event) {
    myFunction($(this));
}

$('selector').on({
    mouseenter: use_myFunction_as_event_handler,
    mouseleave: use_myFunction_as_event_handler
}, 'selector');
```

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right. I accepted @Hecksa answer, because it has a more in depth explanation how the functions work.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function as

```
var myFunction = function(element)
{
   //do something with element
}

$('selector').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        myFunction($(this));
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        myFunction($(this));
    }
}, 'selector');
```

Since you want to pass the argument in myFunction, you have do define it like above